# SQL Server: How to get and use name of the database in SP

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on two different servers with the same structure, one of them is where we develope, and the other one is the live server. My main database (let's call it MainDB) has the same name in both databases, but the others (call those DBi in live server and DB_i in developement server) do not. I have some syncronization stored procedures which transfer data from the databases DBi to MainDB. In the developement server, I use different names then the live server, then after every change in the sync procedures of developement server, I have to change the names of the databases before transfering them to live server.

Now, my aim is to write functions which would return the names of the databases. However, I have no idea what type of data to return in order to use the return value as the name of the database.

For instance, assume I have a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM DB1.dbo.Table1
```

in live server. In the developement server, it's:

```
SELECT * FROM DB_1.dbo.Table1
```

And my aim is to be able to define something like:

```
DECLARE @DBName1 [SOME_TYPE]= GetDBName(@DBID_1)
```

and then use it as:

```
SELECT * FROM @DBName1.dbo.Table1
```

It doesn't have to be exactly like this of course, but the functionality must be the same. You may ask why would I need something like that. I don't wanna change the code before all the transfers. I wanna use the same sp in both servers, but get different names for databases from the functions, as I would only change the return value of the functions in servers for only one time.

Comment: Can you explain more deeply?

Comment: This is a really bad idea.  Why do you need a three part name at all?

Comment: For what it's worth SSDT supports database variables so you can reference the variable and it will substitute its value at deployment time.

Comment: @Andomar The problem is everytime I update the server or everytime I start developing, I have to change the names of the databases and this does not look like a good structure. That's not a good thing at all. The reason I need it is just like why we need config files in projects.

Comment: I second the suggestion that this is a very bad idea. From your explanation I don't understand the need for this complexity.

Comment: Without a three part name, it will use the current DB. Another solution is to use the same DB name in test, using a different Sql server instance.

Comment: i don't exactly understand the problem here. is it the type of database name or what?

Comment: I'll try to explain again. I'm working in two servers and the names of the databases in those two servers are different, even though they have the same structure. I'm calling the names of the databases in live server as DB1, DB2, DB3; and names of the databases in developement (or you can say test) server as DB_1, DB_2, DB_3, where DB1 is identical to DB_1 except its name. That difference causes the usage of different code in some sync stored procedures and I have to change the code before working or before transfering everytime.Why I need it is that, I don't want to change the code everytime.

Comment: Why not rename test from db_1 to db1? Differences between test and production are a continuous cause of issues.

Comment: It's just the policies. The naming method in test is far more better than the naming method in live because in live db there are works of over ten years with different companies but in test, someone created those databases in different names, I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_SomeProc
@DB_Name NVARCHAR(128)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

  SET @Sql = N'SELECT * FROM ' +  QUOTENAME(@DBName1) + N'.[dbo].[Table1] '

  EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql

END
```

**Edit**

```
  DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX);
  DECLARE @DBName nvarchar(50) = 'DBName' 

SET @Query  = N'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@DBName) + N'.dbo.Table'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Query
```

Comment: Well, I'm not going to use it like this, but should understand that I can use a function in an SQL expration like "N'SELECT * FROM ' +  QUOTENAME(@DBName1) + N'.[dbo].[Table1] '"?

Comment: The `QUOTENAME` function basically puts square brackets `[]` around your passed parameter and then passed that string to system stored procedure `sp_executesql` which would treat it as an object name because of the square brackets around it, otherwise it would consider it as a string.

Comment: I've tested it and and it's for a query. But, does it mean that I have to write all the code of the procedure in varchar? Can't I use something like: SELECT * FROM QUOTENAME(@DBName1).dbo.Table1, where @DBName1 is a varchar and name of database?

Comment: No you will have to NVARCHAR not varchar datatype for it. and this is the only way unless to want to handle this on your application level and direct calls to a different database from there.

Comment: Ouw, ok, I changed it to nvarchar, but it still does not seem to work as I wanted. My query is:

DECLARE @DBName nvarchar(50) = 'DBName'
SELECT * FROM QUOTENAME(@DBName).dbo.Table

Comment: see my answer above and read it carefully again. @ZaferSernikli

Comment: Well, I got it but it wouldn't work for me as the procedure (or @Query for you example) I'm going to use is around 500 lines. I cannot write the whole query as nvarchar and then execute it. I need a way to integrate only the name of the database as a variable of type nvarchar, but write the rest of the query as normal.